# Equivalence of the product $\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{i}}$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, products

I want to find an equialent formula of the product $$\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{i}}$$ for $ n\rightarrow\infty$.

My attempt:
Using the equiavlence $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{i}}\sim1-\frac{a}{i}$$ for $i\rightarrow\infty$.
Now, how can I estimate the latter term? Can I say just that it is equivalent to $1$?. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming integer $a,i,n$, $$\frac1{1+\frac ai}=\frac i{i+a}$$$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{1+\frac ai}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\frac i{i+a}={n+a\choose n}^{-1}$$

So, for general $a$, you should expect the Gamma function.

Comment: @PeterForeman Will edit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want jut to know that the product converges to some finite value or diverge.

Comment: @Gustave Well, now that you have the closed form, you can check for yourself!

Comment: Your right, never mind

Comment: @Downvoters comments?